# Image slider auto loop feature

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I am using this slider for a website:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyrot/84sU4/)

I am struggling to achieve two relatively simple things - how to make sure it auto loops through the images and also the controls seem a bit buggy - so if you click on the third nav icon to image three and click back it dosn't display the original image?

I have tried to edit it this with no success - I have also tried to add a fourth slide but it fails?

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {

    //loads default content
    //$('#image-area').load($('.menu_top a:first-child').attr('href'));

    $('.o-links').click(function() {

      // href has to be the id of the hidden content element
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#image-area').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).html($('#' + href).html()).fadeIn(1000);
        });
      return false;
    });

  });

  $(function() {
      $('.o-links').click(function(e) {
          //e.preventDefault();
          $('.o-links').not(this).removeClass('O_Nav_Current');
          $(this).addClass('O_Nav_Current');
      });
  });
```

```
<section id="image-slider-container">
  <div class="image-slider-inner">
    <div id="image-area">
      <div class="img-area-wrapper">
        <img src="img/cookie.jpg" class="actual-img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="image-area2">
      <div class="img-area-wrapper">
        <img src="img/courtyard.jpg" class="actual-img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="image-area3">
      <div class="img-area-wrapper">
        <img src="img/window.jpg" class="actual-img">
      </div>
    </div>       


    <div class="slider-buttons">
      <div class="slider-buttons-container">
        <a href="image-area" class="o-links">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="image-area2" class="o-links">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="image-area3" class="o-links">&nbsp;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>

#image-slider-container {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 5% 0px 0% 0px;

}

.image-slider-inner {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;     
    max-width: 1040px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;

}

#image-area2,
#image-area3 {        
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: none;        
}

#image-area {        
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;        
}

#image-area .img-area-wrapper {

    width: 80%;
    height: auto;     
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

.actual-img {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

.slider-buttons {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin-top: 0px;

}

.slider-buttons-container {

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;

}

.slider-buttons-container a {

    border-radius: 360px;
    border: 1px #C5C5C5 solid;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    outline: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    box-shadow: -2px 1px 2px 0px #ADADAD;
    transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;

}


.slider-buttons-container a:hover {

    border: 1px #C5C5C5 solid;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    background-color: #DAD8D8

}

.slider-buttons-container a:active {

    position: relative;
    top: 2px;

}

.O_Nav_Current {

    border: 1px #999999 solid !important;
    background-color: #DAD8D8 !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#image').html($('#image-area').html()); 

        $('.o-links').click(function() {

          // href has to be the id of the hidden content element
          var href = $(this).attr('href');
               $('#image').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    $(this).html($('#' + href).html()).fadeIn(1000);
            });
          return false;
        });

      });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/84sU4/7/)

Comment: Hey - The fiddle seems to work but not when i move it into my site?

Comment: Have you added the extra div in your html?